# How to merge two tables into one pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a warehouse. Table1 for products came to warehouse. Table2 for products came out from Warehouse. I Need Table3 with total products that are now at warehouse. Excel for Mac 2016. Preferable if each table is placed on separate worksheet. In reality I have more and different columns at each table, but Type and Quantity are the key at each.

```
Table1
Type | Quantity
---------------
A    | 4
A    | 5
C    | 3
B    | 3
C    | 8
B    | 1

Table2
Type | Quantity
---------------
C    | 1
B    | 2
B    | 1
A    | 3
C    | 6

Table3
Type | Quantity
---------------
A    | 6
B    | 1
C    | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a pivot table, just list your products A-Z in one column, then use SUMIFS to get the data from each sheet. Then take one from the other in a third column.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,"A")
```

will add up everything in column B that has an "A" in column A. Repeat for sheet 2 and use cell references rather than the hardcoded value above.

This approach will also work if you need to add more criteria for different columns later.